Restriction of $\mathrm{GL}(n)$ representation to $S_n$
$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}\DeclareMathOperator\O{O}$I'm looking for a reference to cite for the following observation. Given an irreducible representation of $\GL(n)$ labelled by the Young diagram with row lengths $\lambda = (\lambda_1,\ldots, \lambda_r)$, its restriction to the subgroup of permutation matrices $S_n \hookrightarrow \GL(n)$ contains with multiplicity one the representation of $S_n$ labelled by the Young diagram with row lengths $\lambda[n] = (n - |\lambda|, \lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_r)$, with $|\lambda| = \lambda_1 + \cdots + \lambda_r$. I believe this is true for sufficiently large $n\gg |\lambda|$, but I'm not sure of the exact conditions.
More specifically, if we think of the $\lambda$ representation as a Young-symmetrized subspace of $(\mathbb{R}^n)^{\otimes |\lambda|}$, one can say that the $\lambda[n]$ representation is obtained by subtracting from the tensors $a_{i_1 i_2 \cdots i_{|\lambda|}} \in (\mathbb{R}^n)^{\otimes |\lambda|}$ all possible diagonal restrictions, like $a_{jj i_2 \cdots}$, $a_{j i_2 j \cdots}$, $a_{jjj i_4\cdots}$, etc. This is analogous to how one can obtain an irreducible representation of $\O(n)$ by subtracting from the tensors in $(\mathbb{R}^n)^{\otimes |\lambda|}$ all traces, like $\sum_{jk} \delta_{jk} a_{jk i_3\cdots}$, etc, with respect to the Euclidean metric tensor $\delta_{jk}$. That's one way to define the $\O(n)$ irrep labelled by the same Young diagram $\lambda$.
Edit: Some interesting answers have been given, but they are phrased at a higher level of abstraction than I was hoping for. Also, the references given are all quite recent, while the result that I'm asking about I think is much older. However, the bibliographies of these references have proven useful. In particular, I have found that the result that I want (adjusting for somewhat archaic terminology) is essentially Theorem VIII in

Littlewood, D. E., Products and plethysms of characters with orthogonal, symplectic and symmetric groups, Can. J. Math. 10, 17-32 (1958). ZBL0079.03604.

It includes the condition $n-|\lambda| \ge \lambda_1$ and the subtraction of the diagonals as a way to get an irreducible representation when restricting from $\GL(n)$ to $S_n$. Littlewood claims that after his characterization of the fundamental tensors of $S_n$ (Theorem VII) the result is essentially an application of the general method from the earlier

Littlewood, D. E., On invariant theory under restricted groups, Philos. Trans. Roy. Soc. London, Ser. A 239, 387-417 (1944). ZBL0060.04403.

where (Sec.4) he teats in detail the subtraction of traces in the $\O(n)$ and $\operatorname{Sp}(2n)$ cases.
Updated question: Could an expert confirm that the above article is an original reference for the result I described? Also, according to Littlewood, it is obvious that the $S_n$ irrep that remains after subtracting the diagonals is precisely $\lambda[n]$. But does he really prove it, by modern standards?

The paper "Branching from the General Linear Group to the Symmetric Group and the Principal Embedding " by Heaton et al, https://alco.centre-mersenne.org/item/ALCO_2021__4_2_189_0/ and its references, might be a good place to start.

Note that in general the restriction problem is hard: https://realopacblog.wordpress.com/2019/11/17/the-restriction-problem/. But of course you are asking about a special case...

Maybe useful (but over $\mathbb{C}$): the centraliser of $S_n$ viewed in this way in the corresponding analogue of Schur–Weyl duality is the partition algebra, which takes over the role of (the other, usual) $S_n$ as commutant of $\mathrm{GL}(n)$. Wiki: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_algebra

For 'original reference': Littlewood cites Murnaghan's textbook and several of his papers; these are the first place I'd have looked for an earlier proof. Littlewood's papers are not easy to read, and I think it is a subjective judgement how much of his work meets modern standards of rigour. Compare Gordon James' quote (in the Wikipedia article on the Littlewood–Richardson rule): 'The author was once told that the Littlewood–Richardson rule helped to get men on the moon but was not proved until after they got there.'

@MarkWildon: that quote also made me wonder whether there were some important lemmas on the Moon which needed to be brought back to Earth.

@MarkWildon Thanks for having a look. I've checked the references by Murnaghan, but none of them explicitly contain the statement I was looking for (only some indirect hints within the analysis of the Kronecker products of representations $\lambda[n]$ and $\mu[n]$). So without evident prior art, it seems that Littlewood is the primary source.

This is true provided $n - |\lambda| \ge \lambda_1$ and follows from Exercise 7.74 in Stanley, Enumerative Combinatorics II, that the multiplicity of the symmetric group character $\chi^\mu$ in the restriction of the Weyl module $\Delta(\lambda)$ for $\mathrm{GL}(\mathbb{C}^n)$ to the symmetric group is the plethysm coefficient
$$ \langle s_\lambda, s_\mu[1+h_1+h_2 + \cdots ] \rangle $$
where $h_m$ is the complete symmetric function of degree $m$. Everything is defined over the rational field, so this also holds replacing $\mathbb{C}$ with $\mathbb{R}$.
Proof. Take $\mu = (n-|\lambda| : \lambda)$ and note that this is a partition. We may interpret the plethysm $s_{(n-|\lambda|:\lambda)}[1+h_1 + h_2 + \cdots ]$ as enumerating by their weight all semistandard tableaux of shape $(n-|\lambda| : \lambda)$ with entries from the alphabet
$$ \{ 1 \} \cup \{x_1, x_2, \ldots \} \cup \{x_1^2, x_1x_2, x_2^2, x_1x_3, x_2x_3, x_3^2, x_1x_4, \ldots \} \cup \ldots $$
where $1 < x_1 < x_2 < \ldots < x_1^2 < x_1x_2 < x_2^2 < x_1x_3 < \ldots $. (The order within the later sets is not important for this proof, but I've indicated the colexicographic order.)
Observe that one way to make a semistandard tableau of shape $(n-|\lambda|:\lambda)$ with entries from this alphabet is to put $n-|\lambda|$ $1$s in the top row of length $n-|\lambda|$, and then use the monomials $x_1, x_2, \ldots $ for the remaining entries (respecting the semistandard condition). This gives a monomial of degree $|\lambda|$, agreeing with the degree of $s_\lambda$. Any other filling gives too high a degree. Therefore the degree $|\lambda|$ component in $s_{(n-|\lambda|: \lambda)}$ evaluated on this alphabet is $s_\lambda$  and
$$ \langle s_\lambda, s_{(n-|\lambda|:\lambda)}[1+h_1+h_2 + \cdots ] \rangle = \langle s_\lambda, s_\lambda \rangle = 1$$
as required.
For further background see Sami H. Assaf and David E. Speyer, Specht modules decompose as alternating sums of restrictions of Schur modules, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 148 (2020), 1015–1029.
Edit: an explicit embedding. Let $E = \mathbb{R}^n$. Assaf and Speyer use symmetric functions, and so their paper does not give an explicit embedding of the Specht module $S^{(n-\lambda : \lambda)}$ into $E^{|\lambda|}$. I'll show one way to do this by example: take $\lambda = (2,1)$ and $n = 6$. Start with the Young permutation module $M^{(3,2,1)}$ for $\mathbb{R}\mathrm{Sym}_6$ with permutation basis all triples of sets
$$(\{1,2,3\},\{4,5\},\{6\}), (\{1,2,4\},\{3,5\},\{6\}), \ldots .$$
The Specht module $S^{(6-3,2,1)}$ is then the submodule of $M^{(3,2,1)}$ generated, as a left $\mathbb{R}\mathrm{Sym}_6$-module, by
$$ \begin{aligned} v &= \sum_{\sigma \in S_{\{1,3,5\} }\times S_{\{2,4\}}} \mathrm{sgn}(\sigma) \sigma (\{1,2,6\},\{3,4\}, \{5\})
\\ &=  (\{1,2,6\},\{3,4\}, \{5\}) - (\{1,2,6\},\{5,4\},\{3\})\\
 &\quad + (\{5,2,6\},\{1,4\},\{3\}) - (\{5,2,6\},\{3,4\},\{1\} + \cdots . \end{aligned} $$
(The symmetrizing elements correspond to columns of the tableau with rows $126$, $34$, $5$ and I've put the sets in non-increasing order to make it clearer how they come from this symmetrization.) Let $E \cong \mathbb{R}^6$ have basis $e_1, \ldots, e_6$. An explicit embedding $S^{(6-3,2,1)} \rightarrow E^{\otimes 3}$ is defined by homomorphic extension of
$$ \begin{aligned} v &\mapsto \sum_{\sigma \in S_{\{1,3,5\} }\times S_{\{2,4\}}} \mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)\sigma (e_3 \otimes e_4 + e_4 \otimes e_3) \otimes e_5 \\ &= (e_3 \otimes e_4 + e_4 \otimes e_3) \otimes e_5 - (e_5 \otimes e_4 + e_4 \otimes e_5) \otimes e_3 \\ &\qquad + (e_1 \otimes e_4 + e_4 \otimes e_1) \otimes e_3 - (e_3 \otimes e_4 + e_4 \otimes e_3) \otimes e_1 + \cdots \end{aligned} $$
The image is contained in the copy in $E^{\otimes 3}$ of the highest weight representation $\Delta^{(2,1)}(E)$ generated by the highest weight vector $e_1 \otimes e_1 \otimes e_2 - e_2 \otimes e_1 \otimes e_1$; moreover, by the result proved above, the image of $v$ generates the unique $S^{(6-3,2,1)}$ inside the restriction of $\Delta^{(2,1)}(E)$ to $\mathrm{Sym}_6$.
The tensors in the image of $v$ have no $e_i \otimes e_i$ terms, so the image is killed by all the contraction maps in Section 6.1.3 of the paper by Sam and Snowden that Christopher Ryba cites in a comment below. My construction therefore agrees with Sam and Snowden, and the earlier construction by Littlewood now cited in the question. This is the intended interpretation of 'subtracting the diagonals'.

Thanks! I will check the references. Do they mention anything about obtaining the corresponding $S_n$ irrep by subtracting all diagonals, as I indicated in the question?

People have already shared interesting and useful answers, but regarding the construction by imposing tensor relations, a reference is Subsubsection 6.1.3 of Sam and Snowden's paper where the exact tensor relations are described.

I think Proposition 6.1.3 from Sam & Snowden is the form of the statement that I was looking for. Perhaps I can refer to it for a complete modern proof, while citing Littlewood as a 'primary' source. I wish I could credit Christopher Ryba with some of the bonus points for his excellent reference. :-)

No need for bonus points, I'm just glad to have been helpful.
A quick comment: a natural interpretation of "removing diagonals" is to intersect the kernels of the $s_{i,j}$ from the aforementioned paper. This would result in the induced representations mentioned in Nate's answer. To pin down the irreducible $\lambda[n]$ with no other stuff, we must further intersect with the kernels of the $t_i$. This amounts to removing (the span of) pure tensors containing $\sum_i e_i$ (the $S_n$ invariant line in $E=\mathbb{R}^n$) as a tensor factor. This extra step is "removing (full) diagonals in $E$".

Let me denote $k = |\lambda|$. We have combinatorial descriptions of the decomposition of $(\mathbb{R}^n)^{\otimes k}$ as an $S_n$ representation - see here for example.
We can think of this space as the linearization of the set of functions from $[k]$ to $[n]$ with $S_n$ acting via post-composition. Note that $S_k$ also acts via pre-composition and these two actions commute, decomposing this as an $S_n \times S_k$ representation is equivalent to the restriction problem.
Anyway though if $n \gg k$, the only copies of $S^{\lambda[n]}$  that can occur are in the subspace spanned by injective functions from $[k] \to [n]$ -- the non-injective ones only contribute terms $S^{\mu[n]}$ with $|\mu| < k$.
This space spanned by injective functions is something we know how to decompose as a $(S_n \times S_k)$-representation: It is isomorphic to $\bigoplus_{|\lambda| = k} Ind_{S_k \times S_{n-k}}^{S_n}(S^\lambda \boxtimes \mathbf{1}) \boxtimes S^\lambda$. Moreover, $Ind_{S_k \times S_{n-k}}^{S_n}(S^\lambda \boxtimes \mathbf{1})$ is something we can decompose via the Pieri rule: it is $S^{\lambda[n]}$ plus some lower order terms $S^{\mu[n]}$ with $|\mu| < k$.
In terms of $GL_n$ representations this space spanned by injective functions corresponds to the direct sum of the weight spaces for weights conjugate to $(1,1, \dots 1, 0, \dots 0)$ where there are $k$ ones. Call such a sum of weight spaces over an $S_n$-orbit a symmetrized weight space. We can alternatively interpret the above as saying that this symmetrized weight space for $W^\lambda(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is isomorphic to $Ind_{S_k \times S_{n-k}}^{S_n}(S^\lambda \boxtimes \mathbf{1})$ as an $S_n$-representation.
I'll note that in fact this symmetrized weight space is actually irreducible as a $TS_n$-representation, where $TS_n$ denotes the subgroup of monomial matrices (generated by $S_n$ and the torus $T$). So you can't pick out the $S^{\lambda[n]}$ on its own without breaking the torus symmetry, but this symmetrized weight space is pretty close.
